# Sentence Transformer Works Slow

Tags: python, dataframe, performance, nlp, sentence-transformers

I am trying to convert my dataset into vectors using sentence transformer model. I have 1 million rows converted into strings. I run it on Google Colab GPU runtime, but it says it will take around 20 hours to complete.

What can I do to speed up process?

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
retriever = SentenceTransformer("sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2", device = 
device) 

row_vecs = []
for i in row_strings:
  vec = retriever.encode(i)
  row_vecs.append(vec)
```

Comment: Try to make an input of 32-128 strings instead of single string. Most model architectures will allow it, not sure about this exact one though.

Answer (score 1):

you can apply encoding in parallel on all the sentences at once!

```
sentences = ["hi","hello"]
row_vecs = model.encode(sentences)
```